# Determine whether the given map ϕ is an isomorphism of these two binary structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

$\langle M_2(\mathbb{R}), \cdot \rangle$ with $\langle \mathbb{R}, \cdot \rangle$ where $\phi(a)$ is the determinant of matrix $M_{2\times 2}$.

I don't think $\phi$ is an isomorphism because I think it is not onto. For a  real number $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $\phi(r) \neq M_{2\times 2}$. In other words, we cannot use the inverse of $\phi$, a determinant $a$, and get a $M_{2\times 2}$.

If the two binary spaces were $\langle M_1(\mathbb{R}), \cdot \rangle$ with $\langle \mathbb{R}, \cdot \rangle$, then I think $\phi$ would have passed the onto check because $a(\mathbb{R}) = M_{1\times 1}$.

Is my reasoning correct?

---

**Edit with additional work/clarifications:**

The map is not injective because the transpose of matrix $a$ will have the same determinant as $a^T$. Therefore $\phi$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Can't follow your argument, but I think you are over complicating matters. 
 Whatever you mean by isomorphism here, you want the map to be injective. Is it?

Comment: let me work through it more and add some more work

Comment: Okay, is the argument better to follow now?

Comment: Not a single part of your edit makes any sense.

Comment: I want to show that the map is not injective because for a given matrix $M$ and it's transpose, $M^T$, the determinant is the same number. Is at least that the right move in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map *is* surjective. For $r\in\Bbb{R}$ the expression $\phi(r)$ makes no sense, because the domain of $\phi$ is $M_2(\Bbb{R})$, not $\Bbb{R}$.

In stead, show that the map is not injective; show that there are two matrices with the same determinant.

Comment: Okay, I will try to do that and update the main post with my results

Comment: Okay, does my wording show that the map is not injective? I am hoping that I did not leave any ambiguity and everything is clearly defined

Comment: No, not a single part of your edit makes any sense to me.